# WCF increase performance and stop blocking

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a client-server application that delivers market data from server to clients.
Now I've stucked on 2 problems:
1. Bad callback performance. I achived max 1.5K callback's per second
2. When one client starts to "stuck" - all users start to retrieve data veeeery slowly(200 callback per second). 
This is my server binding :

```
<netTcpBinding>
<binding name="Net_Tcp_Binding" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="00:00:30"
  maxConnections="100">
 <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
 <security mode="None" />
</binding>
   </netTcpBinding>
```

and service contract(95% of data delivers using MarketDepthUpdate and EntityUpdate) :

```
namespace TradePlatform.DataDeliveryContracts.ServiceContracts

public interface ITradeServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void InstrumentUpdate(InstrumentInfo instrument);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OrderUpdate(OrderInfo order);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OrderFailedUpdate(OrderFailInfo orderFailed);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MyTradeUpdate(MyTradeInfo myTrade);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void TradeUpdate(TradeInfo trade);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void PortfolioUpdate(DSPortfolioInfo portfolio);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void PositionUpdate(PositionInfo position);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MarketDepthUpdate(MarketDepthShortInfo marketDepth);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void DisconnectUser();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UserUpdate(UserInfo user);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void FileUpdate(FileDataInfo file);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SimulationDataUpdate(SimulationModeData simulationData);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MessageUpdate(MessageId message, params object[] parameters);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void EntityUpdate(DataUpdateInfo updateInfo);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Ping();


}
```

And this is client:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding
        {
            Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
        };
        binding.ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

Comment: You should check a lot more as your WCF conection, what is the load on the server/client. Are you calling serial or parallel. And what is the logic on your server, database? And what is your definition on stuck?

Comment: There are no load on the server (CPU about 5%, 1-3% on net). I have n threads that grab data from buffer and send to a list of clients. Main purpose of server is to take data from providers, convert to our format, process (if needed), send to a list of clients (all clients subscribe on data they need). Stuck - is when one user recieves data slow (for some reasons, usually because of internet connection)

Comment: Can you share your ServiceContract's configuration?

Comment: added to the asked question. If you need something more, please ask me, 'cos this prolbem is very urgent for me :(